# GCC: avoiding long time linking while using static arrays

Tags: gcc

My question is practically repeats [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978664/long-compilation-time-for-program-with-static-allocation), which asks *why* this issue occurs. I would like ot know if it is possible to avoid it.

The issue is: if I allocate a huge amount of memory statically:

```
unsigned char static_data[ 8 * BYTES_IN_GYGABYTE ];
```

then linker (`ld`) takes very long time to make an executable. There is a good explanation from @davidg about this behaviour in question I gave above:

> This leaves us with the follow series of steps:
>
> 1. The assembler tells the linker that it needs to create a section of memory that is 1GB long.
> 2. The linker goes ahead and allocates this memory, in preparation for placing it in the final executable.
> 3. The linker realizes that this memory is in the .bss section and is marked NOBITS, meaning that the data is just 0, and doesn't need to be physically placed into the final executable. It avoids writing out the 1GB of data, instead just throwing the allocated memory away.
> 4. The linker writes out to the final ELF file just the compiled code, producing a small executable.
>
> A smarter linker might be able to avoid steps 2 and 3 above, making your compile time much faster

Ok. @davidg had explained **why** does linker takes a lot of time, but I want to know how can I **avoid it**. Maybe GCC have some options, that will say to linker to `be a little smarter` and to `avoid steps 2 and 3 above` ?

Thank you.

P.S. I use GCC 4.5.2 at Ubuntu

Comment: Try using a static global variable.

Comment: I clarified your question and title a bit, so the reader doesn't have to read right to the very last paragraph in order to learn *what the question is*, or why it is not a duplicate. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @Claudio I **did** use a static global variable.

Comment: @jalf very good changings. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can you then avoid using static global? :) malloc not an option?

Comment: @dbrank0 of course I can (except of insignificant moment: I should change the program (not mine, but from open sources) and do not forget to delete/free this memory), but I want to understand the behaviour of linker and try to change it

Comment: btw: I tried to repeat this with Ubuntu 12.04 default toolchain (gcc 4.6.3 + GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu 2.22) 1.11) and simple code allocating 128GB array builds immediately.

Comment: @dbrank0 And that probably means the gold linker handles this case quite differently than the old linker - so the OP should try with gold too.

Comment: @dbrank0 Unfortunally I can't find binaries of GCC for mt Ubuntu 11.04 (natty) and I can't upgrade OS (for some objective reasons)

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate the static memory in the release version only:

```
#ifndef _DEBUG
    unsigned char static_data[ 8 * BYTES_IN_GYGABYTE ];
#else
    unsigned char *static_data;
#endif
```

Comment: Hmmm. Good idea, but I greatly simplified my code. Acually `static_data` is defined such `MyStruct static_data[ ONE_DIMENTION ][ TWO_DIMENTION ][ THREE_DIMENTION ];` Shurely, I can declare it like `MyStruct ***static_data` and allocate all dimentions in loops, but I'm too lazy to do it )))

Comment: Having a separate compilation unit for that data should also increase compilation time, right? I mean if you put the structure inside a c file and compile it separately?

Comment: Nope. I have a huge **linking** time. Not compilatioin. And yes... this structure lies in separate cpp-file.

Answer (score 0):

I would have 2 ideas in mind that could help:

1. As already mentioned in some comment: place it in a separate compilation unit.That itself will not reduce linking time. But maybe together with incremental linking it helps (ld option `-r`).
2. Other is similar. Place it in a separate compilation unit, and generate a shared library from it. And just link later with the shared library.

Sadly I can not promise that one of it helps, as I have no way to test: my gcc(4.7.2) and bin tools dont show this time consuming behaviour, 8, 16 or 32 Gigabytes testprogram compile and link in under a second.

Comment: When I try to add `-r` option to linker I got the problem similar to this - http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gplusplus/2007-01/msg00058.html As I can see it's old-old problem ((

Comment: @borisbn: Ah you using C++, as far as I remember you shouldnt use -r alone, but instead `-Ur`, dont know if it helps in this error case. So I would put my money into the shared lib approach.